# Change Button label in $A.get("event.force:createRecord") modal popup

Tags: lightning, lightning-data-service

I've got a requirement to change label of Save buttons shown in New Record Modal which pops up when event.force:createRecord is fired.
Just wondering, if this is possible through some event param or I've to create a custom object with similar layout and change the button labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot customize any of the force:createRecord UI at all. You're only allowed to specify the object type, record type, and default field values to use. This would definitely have to be built custom.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same. Customizing would be a huge task.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to do so, but you may be able to achieve this with CSS pseudo elements: [How to replace text with css](https://blog.escapecreative.com/how-to-replace-text-with-css/)